# How to add dynamic class name in button present on Child Component when clicking another button from Parent Component?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have a nuxt.js application, I want to add class name to a button(dynamic button) present in `Child Component` when a button present in `Parent Component` is clicked.
I have tried using `Event Bus`, it is able to send event from parent to child but the dynamic class is not getting appended to the button. The dynamic button will highlight the `CSS` effect. Any suggestions or guide is highly appreciated.

#Parent Component

```
<ChildComponent :id="id"/>
<button @click="sendMessageToChild()" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Click Here</button>
                  
methods: {
    sendMessageToChild() {
        this.$root.$emit('highlight')
    },
}
```

## Child Component

```
<button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded":class="{ highlight }">Buy</button>
<button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded":class="{ highlight }">Buy</button>
<button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded":class="{ highlight }">Buy</button>
<button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded":class="{ highlight }">Buy</button>

data() {
    return {
        highlight: false,
        timer: null,
    }
},
mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('highlight', () => {
        this.highlight()
    })
},
methods: {
    highlight() {
        this.highlight = true
        clearTimeout(this.timer)
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.highlight = false
        }, 2000)
    },
}
```

#CSS effect on click of button `Click Here` , this should be highlighted to all the dynamic button in `Child Component`
#CSS in child component

```
.highlight {
    background:orange,
    color:#fff;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}
```

My answer after editing

Parent Component :

Click Here

```
data() {
    return {
        highlight: false,
        timer: null,
    }
},
methods: {
    sendMessageToChild() {
        this.highlight = true
        clearTimeout(this.timer)
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.highlight = false
        }, 2000)
    },
}

.highlight {
    animation: shake 1s cubic-bezier(0.36, 0.07, 0.19, 0.97) both infinite;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    perspective: 1000px;
}
```

Child Component :

```
<button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded":class="{ highlight }">Buy</button>
<button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded":class="{ highlight }">Buy</button>
<button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded":class="{ highlight }">Buy</button>
<button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded":class="{ highlight }">Buy</button>

props: {
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    highlight: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: false,
    },
},
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interaction between parent and child component should be done using prop instead of event, you could define `highlight` as data property in parent and pass it as prop to child component :

parent :

```
<ChildComponent :id="id"   :highlight="highlight"/>
<button @click="highlight"  class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Click Here</button>
  ...
data() {
    return {
        highlight: false,
        timer: null,
    }
},

methods: {
    highlight() {
        this.highlight = true
        clearTimeout(this.timer)
        this.timer = setTimeout(() => {
            this.highlight = false
        }, 2000)
    },

}
```

child component :

```
<button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded":class="{ highlight }">Buy</button>
<button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded":class="{ highlight }">Buy</button>
<button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded":class="{ highlight }">Buy</button>
<button  class="btn btn-primary btn-block text-center rounded":class="{ highlight }">Buy</button>

...

props:["highlight"]
```